# What type of lawyer (criminal, civil, family, etc.) would I need to help me deal with issues of academic misconduct?

Tags: education, academia

What can stop a university from doing whatever they want and screwing students over in terms of accusing them of cheating, plagiarism, or a misunderstanding of professor authorization of essay re-submission in a second class, trying to take a student's degree or credit away after the course is completed/graduated with little evidence and no proof of circumstantial evidence that truly happened at the time of the incident? Since they are private and go by their own rules and apparently there is no standard policy for how all universities are supposed to deal with issues.

This is in St. Catharines, Ontario, Canada.

Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI there is also an Academia stack exchange where you might be able to get some information 
http://academia.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Sean: Already posted there. http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/82050/what-type-of-lawyer-criminal-civil-family-etc-would-i-need-to-help-me-deal

Answer (score 2):

The obvious (but, I believe, correct) answer is "Education Law".  In the US, there is a professional association called the [Education Law Association:](https://educationlaw.org/)

> The Education Law Association (ELA) is a national, nonprofit member association offering unbiased information to its professional members about current legal issues affecting education and the rights of those involved in education in both public and private K-12 schools, universities, and colleges.

This American association does not include Canadian lawyers, of course;  but the terminology is presumably similar.  Googling "education lawyer ontario" does return a fair number of results.

Comment: OP is concerned with a Canadian university, not a US one.

Comment: @mkennedy:  Fair enough;  I've added a comment to address your point.